# I'm using the RDLC Report Designer in VS2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, report, rdlc

I'm using the **RDLC Report Designer** in **VS2010**

I put a table in my report and design my report, but the problem is the row number for each row in table.

How can I put row number (1,2,3,...)

Result must be like this :

```
1  frank 22545487
2  john  454987465487
3  sarah 874478543
.
.
.
25 bill  1542121
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this on your s.no expresion
=RunningValue(CountDistinct("Tablix1"),Count,"Tablix1")

where TABLIX1=YOUR TABLIX NAME

Comment: Formatting your answer would help a lot

Comment: Thank You Anton..Wish You A Happy Xmas And Happy New Year

Answer (score -1):

you must set the function (RowNumber(Nothing))  on the cell that you want to show row number